# iphone app overlapping problem

Tags: iphone

Whenever I run an app on my iPhone, the app is keep overlapping.

I think it's because I'm using it as a team id.

Does anyone know if I can make multiple apps on an iPhone?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify? What do you mean keeps overlapping? Multiple apps?

Comment: I cannot run/put more than one app on my iPhone, when I make 'appB' after making 'appA' the 'appA' just disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that, in the [provisioning portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles/index.action), you are using an AppID which allows multiple applications simultaneously. Something like **12345ABCDE.com.world.hello.***

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same bundle identifier for each app?  You should be able to create and load as many apps as you want.  Take a look in the info.plist files and see if the bundle identifiers are the same for some reason.